# Combining vectors in APL (creating tuples with elements from each vector)

Tags: vector, apl

I have 2 vectors:

```
a ← 1 2 3
b ← 5 6 7
```

I would like to create a nested array with 2-element vector elements, having one element from a b (tuples), i.e.:

```
┌───┬───┬───┐
│1 5│2 6│3 7│
└───┴───┴───┘
```

How would I do that in APL? I can't find any elastic solution, only `(a[1],b[1]) (a[2],b[2])` (I've also tried Outer product with the `⊃` function but without success).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
⊂[2] a,[1.5]b
```

The first part: `a,[1.5]b` merges the two arrays and creates a two-dimensional array with each column being the content of the variables a and b.

Then, `⊂[2]` encapsulates each row into pairs, resulting in your desired output.

Note that if you are using Dyalog, you might have to use ↑ instead of ⊂. I think this depends on the value of the ⎕ML variable, but I don't use Dyalog so I can't test this.

Comment: The above example is very generic, but you can actually solve your specific case like this: `a ,¨ b`. Silly me for not thinking of that one.